# react on click doesn't work with arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Something is wrong with my code below? I try to use the arrow function, but nothing happens.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  promt() => {
    alert('trigger prompt!');
  },
  render(){
      return(
    <h1 onClick="this.promt()">Hello world</h1>
    )        
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

https://jsbin.com/nisetupaqa/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You have an empty JSBin link...

Comment: @AndrewL. ops, didn't notice that, thanks

Comment: Suggested reading: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html JSX is different than normal DOM attributes. onClick takes an actual javascript function reference, not a string

Comment: `promt() => { }` is invalid syntax for ES6 classes

Comment: @AndrewL. so what is a valid snytax?

Comment: @ThianKianPhin Let me write an answer

Comment: @AndrewL. it doesn't work even I fixed the invalid es6 snytax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some incorrect syntax. `promt() => { ... }` is *invalid* for ES6 classes. To achieve arrow functions, you must *assign it*, as a class property, like so:

```
promt = () => {
    alert("trigger prompt");
}
```

Note that class properties are [an experiment feature](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), in [stage-2](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/), which has not been fully implemented. Per the documentation:

> **Stage-X (Experimental Presets)**
>
> Any transforms in stage-x presets are changes to the language that haven’t been approved to be part of a release of Javascript (such as ES6/ES2015).
>
> *“Changes to the language are developed by way of a process which provides guidelines for evolving an addition from an idea to a fully specified feature”*
>
> **Subject to change** These proposals are subject to change so use with extreme caution, especially for anything pre stage-3.

In the meantime, just use regular ES6 class functions:

```
promt() {
    alert("trigger prompt");
}
```

Also, no commas between functions. Also, use `{ }` to reference functions as handlers, do not use strings. That means that this:

```
<h1 onClick="this.promt()">Hello world</h1>
```

is incorrect. Wrap the reference in curly braces, and remove the parentheses, as you need a function *reference*, not invocation:

```
<h1 onClick={this.promt}>Hello world</h1>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehnxxjtj/1/) that is working.

Comment: why no comma between function? and the es6 part, babel actually is able to transplile and get it to work, I've seen someone used it in production.

Comment: @ThianKianPhin No commas, that's ES6 classes. Babel is able to transpile it because it's using stage-2, the experimental set of plugins not fully implemented. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I see. but u didn't mention 'function' keyword I assume arrow function is workable. Hmm I'm confused now.

Comment: I see. but u didn't mention 'function' keyword I assume arrow function is workable. Hmm I'm confused now.

Comment: @ThianKianPhin what do you mean? Class properties in ES6 are not implemented, but are in development, hence the experimental plugins that you can use to make it work with arrow functions

Comment: This is how lynda's instructor use arrow function in react : http://i.imgur.com/znNTGb0.png

Comment: @ThianKianPhin That's *a stateless component*. That's *completely* different than what you're doing here.

Comment: @ThianKianPhin See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html), scroll down to stateless functions.

Comment: oh I see! ok I sorted that out, but one more question, why don't I need a comma btween function? is it because you use class? If I use createClass I have to put comma btw function, correct?

Comment: `var component = React.createClass({ ... })` is *plain JS*, in which commas *are required* between properties. ES6 classes are different in that they do not have commas.

Comment: thank you so much Andrew, sorted out my confusion! have a nice day friend!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass reference, not result of calling:

```
onClick={this.promt}
```

It called once, then you have undefined in a handler.

```
promt() => {
   alert('trigger prompt!');
},
```

Change to:

```
promt() {
  alert('trigger prompt!');
}
```

You haven't to place arrow and comma.
Also, you can find it while looking in console on jsbin page.

Full code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    promt() {
        alert('trigger prompt!');
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <h1 onClick={this.promt}>Hello world</h1>
        )


  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/nisetupaqa/edit?html,js,console,output doesn't work still

Comment: Don't quote it, put it inside curly braces, like this answer says.

Comment: No quotes, look at vadimka's code and your jsbin `onClick={this.promt}`

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: I noticed it after visiting jsbin.